# why do i get an error when not built and not when built?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I get an error message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" when i try to start my electron app with "electron ." . But when i build the electron app everything works as it should.

```html
async function instancesChanged() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (E:\Nodejs\LogReader\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:280:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Nodejs\LogReader\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:322:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
```